# Topcoder SRM 601 Div 1 Level 1 - Help me understand

Tags: algorithm

The problem statement is [here](https://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=12860&rd=15713)

Can someone please help me understand this problem. The problem statement says,

a positive integer 'X' is chosen and each bag should have atleast 'X' fruits, but in the example they are choosing 0. it is confusing here.

Also, they say "you take exactly 'X' fruits from each bag", then in that case, with example 1, as soon as you choose X=1, your present will be come 1 apple and 1 orange and you are done. isn't it?

Please help me understand this. Also any hints on how the thought process of such kind of problems should be will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: please don't just dump a link to the problem-statement. Instead post the relevant pieces of the task.

Comment: Regarding how to solve this: The number of solutions can be counted in several different ways, but some are much faster than others.  Something to think about: If you know that there is a solution with b fruit in total that has a apples and b-a oranges, and another solution with b fruit in total and a' < a apples and b-a' oranges, do you know anything about solutions with b fruit in total and an intermediate (between a and a') number of apples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us look at the first example (0):

```
orange[1]={1}
apple[1]={1}
```

This means that there is one apple and one orange in the first (and only) bag. You now should choose a X such that there are at least X pieces of fruit in each bag:

This can be 1 or 2

- if you choose 1 there are two possibilities: you take out 1 orange **or**  you take out 1 apple.
- if you choose 2 you have one present: 1 orange **and** 1 apple

**The answer: 3 possible presents**

I hope that makes it a bit more clear for you and you can continue on yourself.

Comment: Thank you for helping me to understand it.